# Calling sql with subroutines embeded

Tags: python, sql, tkinter, sqlite

I'm having a problem whilst trying to execute an SQL line of code:

`sql1 = "select ",(variable.get())," FROM ProductTable WHERE", Queryby.get()
 cursor.execute(sql1)`

When I go to execute these lines of code in the program, it says

`ValueError: operation parameter must be str`

I presume this is because of the fact I am trying to use .get() inside the sql line of code. The reason I assume this is because if I change the code from `cursor.execute(sql)` to `print(sql1)` it says:

`('select ', 'OrderNo', ' FROM ProductTable WHERE', 'This is a test')`

I think the problem is that this isn't all considered a string, but I'm unsure of the resolution on how to call the `.get()` parts of the code without interfering the SQL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Strings can be concatenated using `+`, not `,`. I'm not sure what the `Queryby` part is supposed to do with the string it generates...? Compare it to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using commas, join the strings using `+`:

```
sql1 = "select " + variable.get() + " FROM ProductTable WHERE" + Queryby.get()
```

This will return a string, but note that in general this is an insecure way to build your query. Instead of simply sticking strings to each other please read up on [parameterized queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) to protect yourself from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection), one of the most common security vulnerabilities there is.

I'm not sure precisely what library you are using for your database access, but most support parameterization out of the box.